# Ошибка в ajax запросе, не видит data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, по итогу выдает пустой алерт, и соответственно в файл пхп тоже ничего не приходит, но до файла запрос доходит, подскажите пожалуйста почему?

```
$('#cmd').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tests/index.php",
            data: {name: 'Wayne', age: 27},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
$thedata = $_GET['data'];

$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/templates/test/test.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$thedata);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Добрый день. А что у Вас в php файле?

Comment: alert-ом не очень дебажить console.log() хотя-бы, ну и еще не помешало бы посмотреть в инспектор http запросов

Comment: @IgorOgnichenko пробовал и консольлогом, никак не выводит

Comment: @slo_nik добавил в описание

Comment: Ну и чего Вы ожидаете? Вы же ничего не возвращаете из скрипта.

Comment: @slo_nik окей, у меня сейчас вопрос в том почему сам скрипт на клиентской стороне ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Потому, что Вы ничего не возвращаете в ответе с сервера.

Comment: @slo_nik на сервер сообщение из "data" тоже не доходит...

Comment: Написал всё ответом.

Answer (score 0):

В php файле

```
if(/* выполнено успешно */){
  $answer = ['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'Success'];
}
else{
  $answer = ['type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error'];
}  
echo json_encode($answer);
```

В Вашем jquery

```
        success: function(data){
            $response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(response.typ == 'success'){
                console.log('success')
            }
            if(response.type == 'error'){
                console.log('error')
            }
        }
```

Вот приблизительно так.
Так как Вы сейчас обрабатываете на сервер переданные значения - неверно. Вы должны видеть ошибку

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/slonik/localhost/www/index.php on line 161

Замените последовательность

```
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$thedata);
fclose($fp);
```

на одну функцию

```
file_put_contents();
```